# how to use dismissModalViewController in IPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios4, memory-management

I'm developing an app in which I'm using this so many times while navigating between multiple pages:

```
ABCViewController *abc = [[ABCViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:XYZ animated:NO];
```

But I'm hardly using `[self dismissmodalViewController:NO]` anywhere.

So what problems will arise doing this and how i can do this?

What I know is that I'm putting the viewController in stack again and again, and I don't know how can I clear these viewControllers from stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewController:abc animated:YES];
```